# Count the number of overflows in an operation

Tags: c#, checked

From the large amount of questions on this topic, I know how to detect an overflow:

```
try {
    checked(doSomething());
} catch(OverflowException e) {
    //Handle overflow
}
```

However, is there a way to not just detect whether there has been at least one overflow, but to actually count how many overflows there were?

EDIT: to counter the misunderstandings, I don't want to just count how many operations lead to tone or more overflows, but *how many overflows resulted from a certain operation*.

Comment: No, because as soon as the first one occurs, an exception is thrown. It doesn't continue, so it never even tries the rest of them.

Comment: @vcsjones well, ok, using `checked` was a bad example. Is there anything *else* that I could do?

Comment: the answers below may work, however your exact requirements aren't clear enough to determine if they are applicable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `doSomething` really looks like? `checked` isn't really useful if you've only got a function call.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine? Are you calling this method multiple times? Can you post more code, like where the `try catch` block is located and how it is being called?

Comment: perhaps you want to cast to `long` and check? You question does not make much sense.

Comment: @Bluefire, but why would you need it?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is for integers, write a wrapper class for Int32 where you overload all the operators and sum the overflows in a static variable. Perform your overflow detection in these operators, the simplest (and slowest) is to go the checked/try-catch route, but if you need performance there are smarter alternatives (i.e. comparing signs).

Then replace int with your wrapper class everywhere.

Basic code structure:

```
struct CheckedInt {
     static int s_numOverflows = 0;
     int m_value;

     public CheckedInt(int value) { m_value = value; }
     public static CheckedInt operator +(CheckedInt x, CheckedInt y) {
         try { 
             return new CheckedInt(checked(x.m_value + y.m_value)); 
         }
         catch(OverflowException) { 
             ++s_numOverflows; 
             return new CheckedInt(unchecked(x.m_value + y.m_value)); 
         }
     }
     // ... etc for all operators, you'll also need to implement casts, IComparable(T), IEquatable(T), etc.
}
```

Comment: An alternative to `try`-`catch` is to widen the operands to `long`, then do the arithmetics with `long` (there's space for sum, product, difference), and check if the result is between `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue`. This suggestion was given by leppie in the comments to the question. I'm not sure if it's faster. For division the only interesting case is `int.MinValue / -1` so you can check if that's the exact dividend and divisor.